# pymongo multiple update $in

Tags: pymongo

The following command not working:

**collection.update({'somefield':{'$in':somelist}}, {'$set':{'processed':1}}, False, True)**

Is it possible in MongoDb to make something like that in MySQL:

**update sometable set processed=1 where id in (value1,value2,value3,etc)**

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of the update() method updates a single document and would correspond to the SQL UPDATE statement with the LIMIT 1. With the multi option, update() method would correspond to the SQL UPDATE statement without the LIMIT clause.

Comment: I am using multi option as fourth parameter True, but it doesn't work